# How to automatically generate catagoryId as ObjectId of category ....Nest js, Typescript & Mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs

**book.entity.ts**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Category } from 'src/category/entities/category.entity';

export type BookDocument = Book & Document;

@Schema()
export class Book {
    @Prop()
    title: string;

    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Category.name })
    categoryId: string;

    @Prop()
    subtitle: string;

    @Prop()
    author: string;

    @Prop()
    published: number;

    @Prop()
    publisher: string;

    @Prop({ default: true })
    isActive: boolean;

    @Prop({ default: false })
    isDelete: boolean;
}

export const BookSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Book);
```

**book.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { CreateBookDto } from './dto/create-book.dto';
import { UpdateBookDto } from './dto/update-book.dto';
import { Book, BookDocument } from './entities/book.entity';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {
constructor(@InjectModel(Book.name) private bookModel:Model<BookDocument>){}

 create( createBookDto: CreateBookDto):Promise<Book> {
    const model=new this.bookModel({
      title:createBookDto.title,
      subtitle:createBookDto.subtitle,
      author:createBookDto.author,
      published:createBookDto.published,
      publisher:createBookDto.publisher
    });

    return model.save();
  }

  findAll():Promise<Book[]> {
    return this.bookModel.find().exec();
  }
```

**send data by post method in postman**

```
{
    "title":"Agile Web Development with Rails",
    "subtitle":"Dive into ES6 and the Future of JavaScript",
    "author":"Sam Ruby, Dave Thomas, David Heinemeier Hansson",
    "published":2010,
    "publisher":"O'Reilly Media"
}
```

**after sending data by post method on postman**

```
{
    "title": "Agile Web Development with Rails",
    "subtitle": "Dive into ES6 and the Future of JavaScript",
    "author": "Sam Ruby, Dave Thomas, David Heinemeier Hansson",
    "published": 2010,
    "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",
    "isActive": true,
    "isDelete": false,
    "_id": "62eb4ee69800880cc4a99557",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Why categoryId is not showing?
I think that categoryId should be generated automatically but why its not happening?please help me out,Thanks in advance.....

**category.entity.ts**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';

export type CategoryDocument = Category & Document;

@Schema({ autoIndex: true, collection: `${Category.name}` })
export class Category {
    // Id field.
    _id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId;

    @Prop({ required : true})
    category: string;

    @Prop({ default: true })
    isActive: boolean;

    @Prop({ default: false })
    isDelete: boolean;
}

export const CategorySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Category);
```

Why categoryId is not showing?
I think that categoryId should be generated automatically but why its not happening?please help me out,Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the `categoryId`

In your DTO you are not telling the service which category this book belongs to.

```
create( createBookDto: CreateBookDto):Promise<Book> {
    const model=new this.bookModel({
      title:createBookDto.title,
      subtitle:createBookDto.subtitle,
      author:createBookDto.author,
      published:createBookDto.published,
      publisher:createBookDto.publisher,

      categoryId: 'fiction' // assuming you have a document in the categories collection with _id = fiction
    });

    return model.save();
  }
```